# Flutter Undefined class 'PurchaserInfo'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter project which was working fine since yesterday. Today I am seeing class not found error for couple of packages even though the packages are imported.

**Error**: Undefined class 'PurchaserInfo'.

**Code**:

```
import 'package:purchases_flutter/purchases_flutter.dart';

PurchaserInfo purchaserInfo = await Purchases.purchasePackage(_package);
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 < 3.0.0"

purchases_flutter: ^4.3.1
```

**IDE**:
VSCode or Android Studio

I also checked RevenueCat's [documentation](https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/making-purchases) and they I do not see any error.

I tried flutter clean and flutter pub get.

Please see the following image of the issue.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried "flutter pub get"?

Comment: Yes, I did but still not working.

Comment: Class name has been renamed to `CustomerInfo`. Check the v4.0 api documentation.

Comment: You are right, it has changed to CustomerInfo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also get that error in latest version of reveneucat.
Change PurchaserInfo to CustomerInfo then the problem will be resolved.
some example code here:

```
CustomerInfo purchaserInfo = await Purchases.purchasePackage(
        myProductList.firstWhere(
            (element) => element.offeringIdentifier == productIdentify),
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

I also get that error.  When using an earlier version it works for me.

purchases_flutter: ^3.8.0

Answer (score 1):

ClassName `PurchaserInfo` has changed to `CustomerInfo` in v4.0

Change `PurchaserInfo` to `CustomerInfo`

```
CustomerInfo purchaserInfo = await Purchases.purchasePackage(_package);
```

[image]

Find the full changelog [here](https://github.com/revenuecat/purchases-flutter/compare/3.10.0...4.0.0)